# How to paint the portion of the image inside its border line via using libgdx?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I am creating an image painting app in libgdx where user would touch the portion of the image. e.g If the user touch the wheels of a car that should turn into the selected color.

I don't really know how to specify the custom area around the touch. That can be a wheel, a door which are not always rectangle and circle. I just need an idea to do it. Whether libgdx pixelmap can achive this. I have to paint the image inside the border line of the touch region. I hope my problem is clearly stated.

I woule really appreciate for your time for giving the answers. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look at [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithms.  I don't think there is any built-in support for this in libGDX, but you should be able to implement your own flood fill on a [libGDX pixmap](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html).

Comment: I would really look into the flood fill algo. That seems an elegant solution I hope this could be achievable through libGDX pixmap.